# How can I append user input to a new line whilst also avoiding possible duplicates within my .CSV file using FileWriter?

Tags: java, csv, duplicates, append, filewriter

with this problem I have, I'd like to hit two birds with one stone.

I'm currently trying to output user input from text fields into an existing .CSV file with data already residing within. My first problem stems from not being able to append to a new line, my code is currently appending to the last item in the .CSV file, thus creating an even longer line, not a new line.

Next, I would like to check my .CSV for possible duplicates of the users input. If a user wants to add a Banana to the list, and code checks through the .CSV file and finds a banana within the file, then we can successfully throw an error and warn the user.

Here's my code currently to attempt to try and append to a new line, but somehow it's just not working:

```
    String fileName = "temp.csv";
    try {
        FileWriter fileWriter = 
            new FileWriter(fileName, true);

        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =
                new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

        bufferedWriter.write("\n" + fruitNameField.getText());
        bufferedWriter.write(',');
        bufferedWriter.write(quantityOfFruitField.getText());
        bufferedWriter.write(',');
        bufferedWriter.write(fruitLocationField.getText());
        //bufferedWriter.write(',');

        bufferedWriter.close();

    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Error writing to file" + fileName + "'");
    }
```

While I am wanting 3 different user inputs and to append to a new line, the code above ends up outputting like this: Banana,2,storeOrange,3,store. It seems to be ignoring the new line command.

Now for my second problem, checking against duplicates. For the life of me, I cannot find any resources relating to checking for duplicates within a text file using java.

This question is mainly for appending to a new line, but if I could get any help on this, that would be amazing.

To my knowledge, in order to check for duplicates, I believe I'd have to import my text file and write it to an array, but what if it's a big file?

Once my file is in an array, I'll check if the user input is equal to any text residing within the array, and if it is, throw an error. That is my approach on this subject, please tell me if I can improve on this any way.

Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: BufferedWriter  has a newLine() method.

Comment: Thanks, that solved half of my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to make use of a library like [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to read and write to csv files.

Example:

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class JavaApplication28 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String input = fruitNameField.getText();
        String filename = "temp.csv";

        writeToCsvFile(input,filename);
    }

    private static void writeToCsvFile(String input, String filename) throws IOException {
        if(!isDuplicate(input,filename)){
            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filename,true), ',');
            String[] entries = {fruitNameField.getText(),quantityOfFruitField.getText(),fruitLocationField.getText()};
            writer.writeNext(entries);
            writer.close();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("fruitName already exists.");
        }        
    }

    private static boolean isDuplicate(String input, String filename) throws IOException  {
        boolean found = false;
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String [] nextLine;
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
           for(int i = 0; i<nextLine.length; i++){
               if(nextLine[i].equalsIgnoreCase(input)){
                   found = true;
                   break;
               }
           }           
        }
        return found;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not enormously big, I would suggest to read the whole file and store it in a `Map` whose keys are the words you're adding(which you want to check for duplicates).
On every new line, you can check whether the map contains the key(which costs only O(1) so it's highly efficient).

For the newlines, note that it depends on the environment, it may be `\r\n` (for Windows) or `\n` for Unix/Mac OS. Best is to use `System.getProperty("line.separator");`

Comment: Why not just use a Set instead of a Map. Also, BufferedWriter has a newLine() which abstracts the environment for you.

Comment: Hmm, I've never used map before, how do you suppose I read into it? What would be an example line of code?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis Yes java.util.Set is appropriate, I mentioned Map as data structure concept. For the second point you're right, but it's also good to know for the OP that he can use System.getProperty anywhere outside BufferedWriter context.

Comment: @juiceb0xk You can use java.util.Set. 
Read the file and put the keys in the set. It's a matter of `set.add("key");` 
When appending new lines, always check the set whether it contains that key
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_set_interface.htm